# unity 4.6 UI how to set a slider main volume for all sound?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, slider

I wish someone can tell me how to set audiolistener main volume for a slider with the new UI system.
I mean i know I can do with audio source but how can I do for all audio file togheter that has already a slider volume their own?
When I put the main camera in the On Value change field and set audio Listerner-->volume it says: Missing AudioListener.set_volume

While I did this with old gui system via script now I'm a bit confused how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought...

Create a static class that is global to the entire system and it has a static value for a "MasterVolume" level.  Then, you might be able to add an EventHandler to it that other audio-script controls can subscribe to.  Then, when the master volume gets set, you broadcast to those instances it changed.  Then, in each audio listening can update it's own baseVolume level * the % the MasterVolume is set to.

This way, on some controls that may have a volume of 10%, and another at 60%.
Then, if the master volume gets dropped to say 50%.  The 10% will be dropped to 5% and 60% dropped to 30%, so between them, they retain their same respective volume.  As noted about the audio control, I am not too familiar with that, nor do I have Unity in front of me to reference and test.

```
public static class MyMaster
{
    // Allow any object to subscribe when the master volume changes
    public static event EventHandler VolumeChanged;

    private static float _masterVolume;
    public static float MasterVolume
    {
        get { return _masterVolume; }
        set { _masterVolume = value;
                // now, only if something IS subscribed, call it out
                // and pass the updated volume to them.  This way, you
                // dont have to know when Unity does the update, the 
                // EventHandler immediately sends the broadcast.
                if( VolumeChanged != null )
                    // Send the volume as a PERCENT
                    VolumeChanged( _masterVolume / 100.0f, null );
        }
    }
}


public class YourAudioListener : MonoBehavior
{
    public float BaseVolume = 10.0f;

    public void Start()
    {
        // When your control starts, add itself to the 
        // master event handler for volume
        MyMaster.VolumeChanged += MyMaster_VolumeChanged;
    }

    // This is the local object's instance script that will be called
    // when the master volume has changed.
    void MyMaster_VolumeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Not sure about actual audio control... but...
        tmp.VolumeProperty = BaseVolume * (float)sender;
    }
}
```